# Git merging theirs steps

Tags: git, merge

I am dealing with quite a few binary files generated by a program. Auto merging doesn't work well for these files. What I'd like to do when merging, is quite literally take one copy or the other. It's not ideal, but I think it's the best approach.

Now my understanding, is that if I wanted to take a file from the branch I'm merging from, and completely discard our version, I should do:

```
git merge <branchname>
git checkout --theirs <filename>
git add <filename>
git commit
```

Is this correct, or am I missing something?

I'd like to do it without using .gitignore

Comment: I have been looking for a while on how to resolve conflicts resulting from `git merge -X theirs upstream/master` "both added". `git checkout --theirs .` was the right thing to do! Thank you.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

If your goal is indeed to keep one version or the other, then yes, you will want to use:

```
git checkout <--theirs|--ours> <path>
git add <path>
```

Of course, as you say, it's not ideal. If there's any way you can avoid this, you should. If you can, try to adopt workflow habits which avoid changing those files on divergent branches which will later need to be merged. If the files are generated from tracked content, you really probably do want to ignore them - if you have good reason not to, you might want to generate them from the mergeable tracked content instead, if that's possible.

So, explore all your other options before doing this, but if you must, you've got it right.

Comment: Is it supposed to remain "Both modified" before I add it? I do this, but it generates a new file, with TH at the end :S

Comment: Edit: Yes, it doesn't notify you of the fact you're taking theirs/ours. Just checkout then add.

Answer (score 2):

Look into using .gitignore to ignore generated files.  You may have to do git rm  as well.

Comment: This is true... assuming that the binary files are generated by the program directly from things which are tracked. The OP is likely not in that situation.

Comment: another solution is to mark these files in `.gitattributes` for git to use the `binary` strategy for merging (i.e. do not merge the contents of the files). This way you always get conflicts in case of conflicting changes, which you can then solve yourself.